# .htaccess redirect olddomain/folder to newdomain/otherfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use this in my httpd.config and it works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName olddomain.com
ServerAlias www.olddomain.com
Redirect permanent /FolderName/Filename_with_underscores.html http://newdomain.com/some-folder-with-dashes/?lang=fr
Redirect permanent /FolderName/Other_filename.html http://newdomain.com/some-other-folder/?lang=fr
Redirect permanent / http://newdomain.com/
</Virtualhost>
```

Now I'd like to put this in the .htaccess file in the root of the website.
I have tried several things but it keeps failing.
Does anyone know how to translate this httpd redirect to .htaccess?

There are capitals, dashes and underscores in the url's...

The code below works (but it's only half the story: it redirects all (www.)olddomain.com to the desired folder at newdomain.com):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com\$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://newdomain.com/some-folder-with-dashes/?lang=fr" [R=301,L]
```

Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# All rules only for olddomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^FolderName/Filename_with_underscores\.html$ http://newdomain.com/some-folder-with-dashes/?lang=fr [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^FolderName/Other_filename\.html$ http://newdomain.com/some-other-folder/?lang=fr [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that asap!

Comment: Hi Croises
Unfortunately your solution does not work. It's very similar to one of my trials. The website says 'Page not found' when I type one of the url's like

    http://olddomain.com/FolderName/Filename_with_underscores.html

I tried your solution with escaping - did not work either

Comment: Ok. But that is and was present in my .htaccess since there are more rules for other domains... (simple redirects).

Comment: It can be a problem with your real links or the location of other rules. Because there can be no problem with the rules given here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make further investigations.

Comment: Thanks Croise for your help. I will dig into the .htaccess matter later. Now I agreed with the customer he will not use the redirects no more (in his mailings). Problem solved for me!